# How to install a scoped package from a different registry( package.json setup )

Tags: npm, scope, npm-install, package.json, npm-registry

So I have this package "reusable-components": "^1.0.1" in my package.json
If I hit npm install, it will try to download it from the https://registry/npmjs.org
If I manually try to use npm install reusable-components --registry=http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx , it will try to install it from the registry that I intend to use just for that package

My attempt was to make a scoped package so I made an .npmrc file in the root of my project containing this:

```
# last modified 21 May 2020
; Set a new registry for a scoped package
@verdaccio:registry=http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
```

After this I rewrote package.json with "@verdaccio/reusable-components": "^1.0.1" .
According to the official npm documentation this should work, however, hitting npm install in the console doesn't correctly try to take reusable-components from the registry that I set up for that scope.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you share your package.json file and error details when you try to do npm install?